# Deleting html element from webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I tried to remove element dynamically but the removed element still shows up on screen, and is removed when clicked on the element.

here is the code i used

```
 onPageFinished: (url){
        removeAds(url);
      },
 void removeAds(String url){
      print("asdjkhjahsdk");
      //_controller.loadUrl('javascript: var ad= document.getElementById("_b04pct_2709847"); ad.parentNode.removeChild(ad);');
      _controller.evaluateJavascript('var ad= document.getElementById("_b04pct_2709847"); ad.parentNode.removeChild(ad);');

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('_b04pct_2709847').style.display='none';")`

Comment: did that nothing changed. it might be because the element is dynamically created

Comment: Well then can you locate the element by other attributes? Class, tag, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('_b04pct_2709847')[0].style.display='none';");
```

I guess you forgot the '[0]'. I try to hide the element before load the page. Did you have success?

Comment: OP uses `getElementById` which, unlike `getElementsByClassName`, returns a single element, so there is no forgotten `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since [webview_flutter 3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)    this is how I do this

with as a future that is  `controller = Completer<WebViewController>();`

```
onProgress: (progress) {

        if (progress > 30) {
          //remove the element with class name
          controller.future.then((webviewController) => webviewController
              .runJavascript(
                  'document.getElementsByClassName("td-header-template-wrap")[0].remove();')
              .then(
                  (value) => debugPrint('Page finished running Javascript'))
              .catchError((onError) => debugPrint('$onError')));
        }
      },
```

I do it in onProgress because I want the javascript to run once and only once before the full page loading completes. This can also be done in onPageFinished. Sometimes the tag doesn't exist before the javascript is run which is why it's preferred to do this in onPageFinished.

Answer (score 0):

[image]`THIS WORKS FOR ME (FLUTTER 3)`
webview_flutter 4.0.6
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

I just want to collaborate, to this date there is not much in the Doc,
I created my own solution, based on the event of the controller, I create a render conditional and update the state when the promise is resolved to remove the CircularProgressIndicator() and display the WebViewWidget(controller: controller) , but before I do the javascript change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyExample> createState() => _MyExampleState();
}

class _MyExampleState extends State<MyExample> {
  bool _loading = true;

  late final WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print("start..........");
          },
          onPageFinished: (_) => {
            _onAddToJs(controller),
            print("end.........."),
            setState(() {
              _loading = false;
            })
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse("https://example.com"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Example AppBar')),
      body: _loading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}

_onAddToJs(webViewController) {
  webViewController.runJavaScript(
    '''let aNewHeadElement = document.createElement("h1");
      aNewHeadElement.id = "newHeadElement";
      document.body.appendChild(aNewHeadElement);
      document.getElementById("newHeadElement").innerHTML = "Hello, I was created with javascript";''',
  );
}
```